# python3,boto3,aws ec2 instance's second ip obtain

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Somehow, I had to get second eth1 private ip address of ec2 instances using python3. I can get only ec2 instance-id. I managed to do it,but it is not good code I think.

I tried filters but failed. Instead I use like below.

````
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
def get_sec_ip(instance_id):
    res=ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
    print(res['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['NetworkInterfaces'][1]['PrivateIpAddress'])```

instance_id = 'i-03a0d15992b7bf'
get_sec_ip(instance_id)
````

Is there anybody who did this result using ec2.describe_instances' filters?

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying is wrong with your current implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other possibility is to use [Instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance) object:

```
 ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
 instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)
 print(instance.network_interfaces[1].private_ip_address)
```

The filter is not used for limiting output, but limiting number of instance descriptions return. For example, the `describe_instances` can return 10 instances (not in your case, but in general), and `Filters` can limit it to only 2 based on some criteria, e.g. instances only in a given subnet.